# SP Help (Invalid Column Name)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

With a MS SQL Stored Procedure I am getting the following error "Invalid Column Name NavigationID".

Can anyone let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

```
DECLARE @NavigationID INT
SET @NavigationID = 5 

CREATE TABLE #tmp (NavigationID int , ParentID int);
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT NavigationID, ParentID FROM Nav;

    WITH Parent AS
    (
        SELECT NavigationID, ParentID FROM #tmp WHERE NavigationID = @NavigationID
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.NavigationID, t.ParentID FROM Parent
        INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.NavigationID =  Parent.ParentID
    )

    SELECT NavigationID FROM ParentID
    WHERE NavigationID <> @NavigationID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you posted you get.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid object name 'ParentID'.
```

Change `FROM ParentID` to `FROM Parent`.

You also need a column `NavigationID` in table `Nav`.

Try this:

```
declare @Nav table(NavigationID int, ParentID int)

insert into @Nav
select 1, null union all
select  2, 1 union all
select  3, 1 union all
select   4, 3 union all
select   5, 3 union all
select 6, null union all
select  7, 6

declare @NavigationID int;
set @NavigationID = 5;


with Parent as
(
  select NavigationID,
         ParentID
  from @Nav
  where NavigationID = @NavigationID
  union all
  select t.NavigationID, t.ParentID
  from Parent
    inner join @Nav t
      on t.NavigationID =  Parent.ParentID
)
select NavigationID
from Parent
where NavigationID <> @NavigationID;
```

Result:

```
NavigationID
------------
3
1
```

Replace @Nav with whatever table you are using. @Nav is only here so that this code can be copied and tested.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Once changed it still says "Invalid Column Name NavigationID".

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'NavigationID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'NavigationID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'NavigationID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'NavigationID'.

Comment: What does that table `Nav` look like?

Comment: Nav has NavigationID, ParentID (Plus other columns) but it does contain them.

Comment: @techco1 - There is nothing wrong with your code other than `FROM ParentID`. Your problem is elsewhere. BTW, why do you have a temp table? It does not seem to add much value.

Comment: That's odd. Maybe you've got a better idea of how to do it? Basically I want to get all the NavigationID's that are above. i.e. Get the levels above.

Comment: @tehco1 - I would do it like you but use `nav` directly in the recursive cte. Here is some code where I let a table variable `@nav` take the place of your table `nav`. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/105146/reqursive-query-get-parents. It does the same as yours only slightly different formating.

Comment: Thanks for that. When I put that code into the query editor, I got an error! Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near '​'.

Comment: I don't know why people are so tight with giving out points, good solution and you spend a long time on resolving the question and explaining the answer +1 from me.